# ClosedByInterruptException - Reopen the File channel

Tags: java, nio

I am writing code to a program which generates a Thread.interrupt and invalidates all NIO channels.

Once that happens, I need to recover the data in those channels but I cannot figure out a way to do so since all channels are "invalid" in the sense that checking *FileChannel.isChannelOpen()* returns TRUE but calling either FileInputStream.getChannel() or FileOutputStream.getChannel() subsequently throws a *ClosedByInterruptException* so the channel is neither open nor closed...

```
File theFile = new File("myfile.txt"); //this file was already open in another function and has been "invalidated" by Thread.interrupt() call

boolean isOpen = FileChannel.isChannelOpen() //returns true
fins = new FileInputStream(theFile).getChannel() //throws ClosedByInterruptException 
fops = new FileOutputStream(theFile).getChannel() //throws ClosedByInterruptException
```

Explicitly closing the channel and then reopening it reproduces the problem.

Copying the file using *Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);* doesn't help either, since I'm assuming in Java7 it uses NIO underneath and it just moves the same channel pointer here

Comment: it seems once the thread has been interrupted you cant open any channels on that thread. if u try it`ll throw ClosedByInterruptException. before opening the channel i changed the current thread interrupted status by calling Thread.interrupted(); it worked for me

Comment: yes, thanks, that worked for me as well - now I can reopen and read/write channels